# What is the worshipping place of Hayagriva mentioned in Yuddha Kanda?

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, avatars, hanuman, lokas

One of the famous incidents from the Ramayana is Hanuman bringing the herbal mountain containing Sanjivani herbs. His journey towards the Himalayas is described in the [Yuddha Kanda Sarga 74](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddhasans74.htm). He sees the abodes of different Gods there. There is a shloka which says he sees Kailasa, Brahma Loka, Brahma Kapala (in Badrinath) near Himalayas etc.,

> स ब्रह्मकोशं रजतालयं च |
>   शक्रालयं रुद्रशरप्रमोक्षम् |
>   **हयाननं** ब्रह्मशिरश्च दीप्तं |
>   ददर्श वैवस्वत किङ्करांश् च || ६-७४-५९
>
> sa brahmakośaṃ rajatālayaṃ ca |
>   śakrālayaṃ rudraśarapramokṣam |
>   **hayānanaṃ** brahmaśiraśca dīptaṃ |
>   dadarśa vaivasvata kiṅkarāṃś ca || 6-74-59
>
> He saw the abode of Brahma the lord of creation, Kailasa the abode of Shiva the lord of dissolution, the abode of Indra the lord of celestials, the arrow-discharging place of Rudra, **the worshipping place of Hayagriva**, the horse-faced form of Vishnu, the shining place at which Brahma's head fell down, the sun-god and Kimkaras. [[6-74-59]](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga74/yuddhasans74.htm#Verse59)

From the above shloka, many of the places can be identified but I could not identify what is the place where Hayagriva is worshipped.

What is the realm (loka) where Hayagriva, the Horse faced form of Vishnu is worshipped?

Comment: As you had answer in question where brahmas head fell down.. ie. pushkar I believe

Comment: @PrasannaR AFAIK, It is Brahma kapalam near Badrinath where Brahma's head fell down from the hand of Shiva. That place is considered sacred and famous for shraddha rituals.

Comment: I Agree.. Thanks infact there is more to mystic to hygriva then any other avatar.. Hygriva worshipped in brahma loka I believe because he is constantly chanting veda..one main upasena for daily Gayathri japa is hygriva as vahrithi...but there is Somaksura/hyagriva asura who stole veda and killed by matsya avatara.. that is why in devara upasane we say brathirama mukhya pranathargatha hygrivaya namaha om. .because for every name you have some Asura with same name

Comment: Since, Haya-shiras is God Vishnu's avatara, the shlokam may be referring to Badarinath. Brahma-shiras is there too. Also, the flight path from Badrinath is close to Dronagiri (where the herbal mountain was picked up from).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to sources in Srimad Bhagavat Purana, it discusses, different varshas, with different inhabitants and rulers, Hayagriva is mentioned there:

> "In this chapter Śukadeva Gosvāmī describes the different varṣas of Jambūdvīpa and the incarnation of the Supreme Lord worshiped in each.
>
> **The predominating ruler of Bhadrāśva-varṣa is Bhadraśravā. He and his many servants always worship the incarnation known as Lord Hayagrīva. At the end of each kalpa, when the demon Ajñāna steals the Vedic knowledge, Lord Hayagrīva appears and preserves it. Then He delivers it to Lord Brahmā.**
>
> In the land known as Hari-varṣa, the exalted devotee Prahlāda Mahārāja worships Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva. (The appearance of Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva is described in the Seventh Canto of Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam.) Following in the footsteps of Prahlāda Mahārāja, the inhabitants of Hari-varṣa always worship Lord Nṛsiṁhadeva to receive from Him the benediction of being engaged in His loving service. In the tract of land known as Ketumāla-varṣa, the Supreme Personality of Godhead (Lord Hṛṣīkeśa) appears in the form of Cupid. The goddess of fortune and the demigods living there engage in His service day and night. Manifesting Himself in sixteen parts, Lord Hṛṣīkeśa is the source of all encouragement, strength and influence. The conditioned living entity has the defect of being always fearful, but simply by the mercy of the Supreme Personality of Godhead, he can rid himself of this defect of material life. Therefore the Lord alone can be addressed as master. In the tract of land known as Ramyaka-varṣa, Manu and all the inhabitants worship Matsyadeva to this very day. Matsyadeva, whose form is pure goodness, is the ruler and maintainer of the whole universe, and as such He is the director of all the demigods, headed by King Indra. In Hiraṇmaya-varṣa Lord Viṣṇu has assumed the form of a tortoise (Kūrma mūrti) and is worshiped there by Aryamā, along with all the other residents. Similarly, in the tract of land known as Uttarakuru-varṣa, Lord Śrī Hari has assumed the form of a boar, and in that form He accepts service from all the inhabitants living there."

https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/5/18/18_summary

Answer (score 0):

If the place of hayagriva's worship need not be on earth, then there are many places where he could be worshipped. Swami Sri Vedanta Deshika in his hayagreeva stotram has documented the Lord's relation with many other revered ones.
दाक्षिण्य रम्या गिरिशस्य मूर्तिः
देवी सरोजासन धर्मपत्नी ।
व्यासादयोऽपि व्यपदेश्य वाचः
स्फुरन्ति सर्वे तव शक्ति लेशैः ॥ ७ ॥
This verse has stated that the deities revered for bestowing knowledge and wisdom(Dakshina murti who is Shiva in disguise, Saraswati & Vedavyasa) have received a complete drop of his shakti for them to become what they are.
Having our Acharya's statue or photograph in our houses is common to the habitants of earth as well Kailasha or Satya Loka.
So Bhagavan Hayagriva could be worshipped at every abode mentioned in the verse of Sri Valmiki.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! You may also want to check the section on [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)